# Prove $\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$ is an integration factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $ \frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$, when $Mx-Ny$ is not identically zero, is an integrating factor for the equation: $$ M dx + N dy = y f_1(x,y)dx + xf_2(x,y)dy = 0$$

My approach is to show $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ after multiplying the equation by the integrating factor. However, I am struggling with the following step. Once I get,

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{f_1}{x(f_1-f_2)}\right) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{f_2}{y(f_1-f_2)}\right) = \frac{f_2\left(-y\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} +x\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\right) + f_1\left(y\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} -x\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}\right) }    {xy(f_1-f_2)^2} $$

then I struggle to see how this is identically zero.  I don't understand how

$$ y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = x \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

where the function $f(x,y)$ applies to both $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: Where did $f(xy)$ come from? There is a lot of extraneous notation here. So $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ are arbitrary functions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I guess $f_1, f_2$ are the two partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: What are $M'$ and $N'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$yfdx+xgdy=0$$
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
Multiply by the given integrating factor. :
$$ \frac M {Mx-Ny}dx+\frac N {Mx-Ny}dy=0$$
For exactness we need:
$$\partial_y \frac M {Mx-Ny}=\partial_x \frac N {Mx-Ny}$$
Multiply by $xy$ both sides:
$$y\partial_y \frac {Mx} {Mx-Ny}=x\partial_x \frac {Ny} {Mx-Ny}$$
Note that we have:
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{d(f)}{d(xy)} \frac {\partial xy}{\partial x}=y\frac{d(f)}{d(xy)} $$
  And 
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{d(f)}{d(xy)} \frac {\partial xy}{\partial y}=x\frac{d(f)}{d(xy)}$$
So that we have:
$$\frac{d}{d(xy)} \frac {Mx} {Mx-Ny}=\frac{d}{d(xy)}  \frac {Ny} {Mx-Ny}$$
$$\frac{d}{d(xy)}  \left (\frac {Mx} {Mx-Ny}- \frac {Ny} {Mx-Ny}\right )=0$$
$$\frac{d (1)}{d(xy)}=0$$
This is true.

---

For your question why we have:
$$y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = x \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$
$$y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial xy}\frac {\partial xy}{\partial y} = x \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial xy}\frac {\partial xy}{\partial x}$$
$$xy\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial xy} = xy \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial xy}$$

Which is true.

---

after multiplying the equation by the integrating factor. However, I am struggling with the following step. Once I get.......then I struggle to see how this is identically zero.
$$E=\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big(\frac{f_1}{x(f_1-f_2)}\big) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(\frac{f_2}{y(f_1-f_2)}\big)  $$
$$E=\frac 1x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \big(\frac{f_1}{(f_1-f_2)}\big) - \frac 1 y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(\frac{f_2}{(f_1-f_2)}\big)  $$
$$E=\frac{d}{d(xy)} \big(\frac{f_1}{(f_1-f_2)}\big) - \frac{d}{d(xy)}  \big(\frac{f_2}{(f_1-f_2)}\big)  $$
$$E=\frac{d}{d(xy)} \left (\frac{f_1}{f_1-f_2} -  \frac{f_2}{f_1-f_2}\right )  $$
$$E=\frac{d(1)}{d( xy)}  \implies E=0$$